# Use timer with RxJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I would like to make a request to an endpoint every 10 seconds and stop the request and the timer when a redux action (POLLING_STOP) comes in.
I am using **react**, **redux**, **redux-observable**, **rxjs6.4.0**.

[image: getRatesEpic code]

I took the code from https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html

But I cannot manage to make it work using the interval/timer http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html.

Answer (score 0):

Solved refactoring getRatesEpic like:

[image]